# Converting string templates to usable, ember template

Tags: ember.js

My api gives me template strings like `'[[user]] commented on 6 images'` and then a data object like `{user: {val: 'Daniel', id: '...'}}`.

I'm trying to figure out how to make a helper to convert that into a usable HTMLBars template, add a link-to component for the user, and output it. So essentially get the helper to return something like

```
'{{link-to user.val 'user' user.id}} commented on 6 images'
```

that's actually usable in a template.

I've tried something along the lines of `Ember.HTMLBars.template('{{link-to ...}} commented...')` but not really sure how to go from there. Do I need to include the ember-template-compiler? I'd like to try to avoid it since it adds a few hundred kbs to vendor.js. I'm also using ember-cli if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

You typically don't want to directly create to a HTMLBars template. Try refactoring your code so you are using a component or route template.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom helper:

```
// app/helpers/custom-template.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export function customTemplate([ template, data ]) {
  return template.replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/, (_, id) => data[id].val);
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(customTemplate);
```

You can implement the logic yourself (as I did) or use Handlebars.

Usage:

```
{{custom-template commentTemplate commentData}}

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  commentTemplate: '[[user]] commented on 6 images',
  commentData: {
    user: {val: 'Daniel', id: '...'}
  }
});
```

---

### UPDATE

You can break the template down into an array of links and non-links, then render them in sequence

```
// app/components/custom-template.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  parts: function() {
    return this.get('templateString').split(/(\[\[.*?\]\])/).map(token => {
      let match = token.match(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/);
      if (match) {
        let type = match[1];
        let { val, id } = this.get('data')[type] || {};
        return {
          isLink: true,
          type, // 'user'
          val, // 'Daniel'
          id // '123'
        };
      }
      return token;
    });
  }.property('templateString')
});


// app/templates/components/custom-template.hbs
{{#each parts as |part|}}
  {{#if part.isLink}}
    {{link-to part.val part.type part.id}}
  {{else}}
    {{part}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Usage:

```
{{custom-template templateString=commentTemplate data=commentData}}

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  commentTemplate: '[[user]] commented on 6 images',
  commentData: {
    user: {val: 'Daniel', id: '123'}
  }
});
```

Output:

```
<div class="ember-view" id="ember389">
    <a class="ember-view ember-transitioning-in" href="/user/123" id="ember397">Daniel</a>
     commented on 6 images
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is that I need to return some of the text in the string as an [ember link component](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.LinkComponent.html) which is the main obstacle. So the template should output AND render as if I were doing `{{link-to 'Daniel' 'user' daniel}} has commented on 6 images`